# Neo4j Browser - Bug on create node?

Tags: neo4j

I dont know if it cpuld be an issue/bug.

When you create a node without variable, server creates "zombie gray" nodes

Example: CREATE (Expedient {id_exp: 'MAPSAN_0004', name: 'contractual', dateCreation: '16/03/2022', dateExpiration:'16/03/2023'})
and run it 2 o 3 times.

You will see in console result for each command:
Created 1 node, set 4 properties, completed after 2 ms.

But when you want to match the nodes, per example:
MATCH (e:Expedient) RETURN e
you will not find de "zombie" nodes, only if run:
MATCH (e) RETURN e

you will see all nodes.

Is it a good behaviour?
Thx in advance community!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just missing a colon to define the node label.

```
CREATE (:Expedient 
  {id_exp: 'MAPSAN_0004', name: 'contractual', dateCreation: '16/03/2022', dateExpiration:'16/03/2023'})
```

If you don't include the colon, the Cypher treats it as a reference variable that you could refer to later in the same statement:

```
CREATE (e:Expedient {id_exp: 'MAPSAN_0004', name: 'contractual', dateCreation: '16/03/2022', dateExpiration:'16/03/2023'})
CREATE (e)-[:REL]->(:Node)
```

Another thing, you might want to store the dates as date format and not string.